# $stateChangeSuccess getting hit twice

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an $http call that is made inside of a function getRoutes that fires off whenever that state has changed:

```
  $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event) {
    $scope.getRoutes($stateParams);
  })
```

I have another function that changes a state parameter and then calls $state.go():

```
  $scope.bindSelectedRoute = function(){
    $stateParams.pickup_route= this.d.pickup_route;
    $state.go('track.search', $stateParams);
  }
```

My problem is that the http call keeps being made twice. First with the $stateParams correct and then a second call with an empty object getting passed. I'm assuming this is a core part of angular that I'm missing.

Any hints?

Best.

Answer (score 0):

I can't suggest refactored code for you but I believe the answer is because you did a $state.go(). You already told the app to fire $scope.getRoutes($stateParams) when the stateChangeSuccess is fired so when $state.go() fires and it successfully changes the state, $scope.getRoutes($stateParams) gets fired again.